# 3 dot setting menu for android apps with custom title

Tags: java, android, settings, contextmenu

in an android app,
if you create a new project,

then automatically the 3 dot settings menu is created on phones where it is needed

*and it is handled the same way as it would have in older versions by:*

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

if you create a custom title, you have to add the 3 dot menu yourself

**how do I know when it is needed?** meaning phones that don't have the settings button

also how do i create a context menu that is customized and attached to the 3 dot button

**Edit:**

after a disscusion with Shobhit Puri, I understood that I was not considering the actionbar, since I am using a minimum API 8, I don't have it,

so there is the option that CommonsWare just supplied to check if the settings menu exists (I still need to check if it exists in API 8)

Shobhit Puri's suggestion was:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
setContentView(...) ; 
ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
ab.setTitle("My Title"); 
ab.setSubtitle("sub-title") ;
```

but that of cores requires API 11 or the support library V7
either way I am excepting Shobhit Puri's answer, because of all his help, and I will post my final solution when I know it works

also thanks to CommonsWare for a nice answer

**Edit2:**

I decided to go with CommonsWare solution for now, I wrote it like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            if (!vc.hasPermanentMenuKey()) {
                setting_dots.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setting_dots.setOnClickListener(this);
                registerForContextMenu(setting_dots);
            }
        }
```

ideally I think you should use the actionbar, because it provides you with most of the work, but it has a lot of compatability issues with API 8 which for now I would rather avoid

Comment: the 3 dot menu is only shown when there is no physical menu button on the device. If your menu item has ' android:showInAction="never" ', the item will be shown in the 3 dot menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dumazy pointed out that the Action bar's Menu Overflow icon is only shown on those devices which do not have a hardware menu-button.

> How do I know when it is needed? meaning phones that don't have the settings button

This is handled by Android itself. You don't need to worry.

> how do i create a context menu that is customized and attached to the 3 dot button

You can just have a an xml file inside `Menu` folder in `res`. Then you can specify the xml file inside the MenuInflater. Eg:

lets name it `list_menu.xml`

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
        android:title="@string/menu_string_1" 
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
        android:title="@string/menu_string_2" 
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

In the `onCreateOptionsMenu` you can set it as:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This menu would be attached to the overflow-icon and have the items that you want to show when it is clicked. There are some hacks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134703/how-to-always-show-android-settings-button-on-actionbar/18134752#18134752) which can show the overflow-icon on all devices but using them is highly discouraged. Let android handle this itself.

You seem to use Title bar. Instead, try to use Action Bar for the same.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I have tried this, but couldn't get it to work. did you guys understand that I am using a custom title?

Comment: Was there any error or no menu opened when you clicked the `menu` button on your device? Was there any button?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, but I was asking that is there a `Menu` button on your device ?

Comment: I am testing on two devices, and the one I am interested about is the device without a menu button

Comment: okay so your problem is that on device without the menu button it does not show.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36194/discussion-between-amir-f-and-shobhit-puri)

Comment: Can I use the same on each of the items of the recyclerview?

Comment: hi there, I have used the exact same java code as you. The 3 dots menu shows up on my action bar but when I press it, nothing happens (when the overflow menu is suppose to show)

Answer (score 1):

> how do I know when it is needed? meaning phones that don't have the settings button

[Call `hasPermanentMenuKey()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29) on a `ViewConfiguration`.

> also how do i create a context menu that is customized and attached to the 3 dot button

By programming. Since you are not using an action bar, it is impossible to give you specific advice that would be relevant.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it only exists in API 14, I have edited the post, and will post my final solution when I know it works

Comment: @Amir.F: All compliant devices with API Levels 11-13 had no MENU key. All complant devices with API Levels 10 and below had a MENU key. Hence, you only need this method on API Level 14+.

Answer (score 0):

***Google says Actionbar overflow only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. Phones with menu keys display the action overflow when the user presses the key.***
If you still want to implement this you may follow this solution.

Click [here](http://nishantcshah.blogspot.in/2014/04/3-dot-menu-android-explained) for your reference.

Just copy this method in your activity and call the method from onCreate method

```
 private void getOverflowMenu() {
    try {
       ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
       Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
       if(menuKeyField != null) {
           menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
           menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

---

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.