# Overflow menu's 3 dots are not showing up in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I am new to android and I am trying to create an overflow menu.

The 3 dots on the `ActionBar` are not showing (even after changing the app theme). After changing the app theme, it gets shown on the center of the screen "Android..CoordinatorLayout" how to get these 3 dots?

My `menu_main.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/rtfm" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please show us the code for your menu XML - you should use `android:showAsAction="never"` to get your overflow.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here: [Android ActionBar items as three dots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627659/android-actionbar-items-as-three-dots)

Comment: i have added the code for menu XML

Comment: @AbdulRafay Which device are you testing on? It will only show up on devices that don't have hardware `menu` button. Check [3 dot setting menu for android apps with custom title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428396/3-dot-setting-menu-for-android-apps-with-custom-title/18428520#18428520)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should need something like this.

A `menu.xml` layout for the items under the `res/menu` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    ...
</menu>
```

Then in your `Activity` you must include this methods.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // Do something

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick at Activity's onCreate:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    //Show dots:
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");

        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }

} else {
    //isResumed = true; ............. do something.....
}
```