# Eclipse - running on real device

Tags: android, eclipse

I have started testing my app in my Samsung Note 2 (real device). In installed it using [this guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). However I have few questions if someone please help me:

1) Once I run my app in the device, does it install anything in my mobile (i have database use as well)? If so, what is the proper way to close the connection so that all installed things get deleted automatically?

2) If I change my code and run it again to check, what happens to the previous installation? Does it override or so?

3) When I use AVD with 5.7 inch screen, it shows menu button perfectly. But in my Note II, 3 menu button (out of 5) are shown in the bar, but rest are missing though I set android:showAsAction="ifRoom" for all of them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) installed in /data/com.yourapp.pkgname/ , no auto delete, you should uninstall it manually

2) Old one will be overrided

3) It might because your AVD is m-dpi/h-dpi but your phone is h-dpi/x-hdpi

Comment: thanks for reply .. can you please explain number 3 and how I can tackle the issue? I want it to show them as icon, as many as possible, then rests should be show in menu dropdown.

Comment: It is not easy to explain, please read through this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... btw, about point 3, it is not for dpi issue, it is because note II has a physical menu button at the bottom of the phone. And thanks to Reinier, I came to know if device has a menu button, it does not show the menu button on top. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739498/android-action-bar-not-showing-overflow#comment12386902_9739498

Comment: You mentioned in your question that on Note phone 3 menu buttons out of 5 are displayed... But if you have physical menu button, all the menu items should be hidden and waiting for your menu press, right?

Comment: well, I think as I have android:showAsAction="ifRoom" for all, 3 buttons were accommodated in the action bar to show as con, rest 2 buttons were shown in overflow (like dropdown) .. but I didn't have the usual icon for overflow menu, so I was confused where they were gone.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it does perform a "normal" installation of your app. There is no automatic cleanup, so you have to remove any installed packages manually.

2) It will install the changed package to your device, any previous installation of your package will be gone. It will keep any application private data though.

3) Probably there is not enough room to display all of them, you did request "ifRoom" so it will only place them there if it fits.

Comment: thanks for reply .. How can I show them as icon as many as possible, then rests show in dropdown (for example, 2 as icon, rest 3 in menu tree dropdown).

Answer (score 1):

1) Once I run my app in the device, does it install anything in my mobile (i have database use as well)? If so, what is the proper way to close the connection so that all installed things get deleted automatically?
Answer: When u install your app on device, it will get create a database, sharedperferences and other files that u have created in your application. but to delete the databases you have manually install the app or clear the data from Setting --> app.

2) If I change my code and run it again to check, what happens to the previous installation? Does it override or so?
Answer : The newer version of the app will be overridden by older one, and you can see the new changes from the app.

3) When I use AVD with 5.7 inch screen, it shows menu button perfectly. But in my Note II, 3 menu button (out of 5) are shown in the bar, but rest are missing though I set android:showAsAction="ifRoom" for all of them.
Answer: When u run the app on actual device, os will detect what ever the available space to display the menu items.. so it is not your hand, but you can decide which item you want first.

Hope this help you..
Enjoy..!!!!