# add action overflow to SystemUI

Tags: android, overflow, action

I have tried to add an action overflow (the 3 dots) to the SystemUI (where the 'back', 'home', and 'recent apps' are), but could not find an example of how to do that.
I do have an example of an app that uses it:

[image: Example]

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Shachar

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739498/android-action-bar-not-showing-overflow?rq=1) help?

Comment: What you want is an indication of an out-of-date, unmaintained app. Please allow the overflow to be opened from the action bar (for devices without a MENU key) or the MENU key. You can read more about this at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a tragedy what happened with the android. If you want Fullscreen app (No TitleBar, No Actionbar), and device have **NO** HW menu button. You are no able to access menu! Let's take a look at the image in question, there are three standard sysytem menu buttons. WHY they removed "menu" - three dots from android? There is plenty of room for it. I don't understand. **Android architects please give to us the menu butoon back!** It looks like a joke, but I did not find any good solution for fullscreen apps.