# How to show action bar overflow menu if user clicks three dots image in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-actionbar-compat

Can anybody explain how to show action bar overflow menu if user clicks three dots image in Android? Is it possible to show in Android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the power to add a comment but according to your question it seems to me that you want to explicitly display the overflow button, like to override it. There is this guy who wrote about it in this post and I'm going to repeat it here:

```
private void getOverflowMenu() {

  try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
      menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
      menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The post is here - [Android action bar not showing overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739498/android-action-bar-not-showing-overflow).

Check the above post.