# Not able to get the overflow feature for actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

### `What i am trying to do` ::

[image]

### `What is happening` ::

[image]

---

**My code**::

**actionbar_sort_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/featuredID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_featured"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Featured"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dealsID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_deal"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Deals"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/inviteID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Invite or Share"/>

</menu>
```

**Manifest code**::

```
<application
        android:name="com.myApp.utilities.AppController"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**Theme i am using**::

```
android:Theme.Holo
```

**Support library** ::

```
android-support-v4.jar
```

---

### {EDIT}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/featuredID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_featured"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Featured"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dealsID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_deal"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Deals"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/inviteID"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Invite or Share"/>

</menu>
```

**error i am getting**

No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package com.myApp

Comment: If your using support library should you be not using Themes derieved from `Theme.AppCompat`?

Comment: To make all the menu items appear in overflow menu you have to use "never" value for android:showAsAction.

Comment: @Raghunandan ..... Which theme should i need to use ?

Comment: @CasperSky what does your activity extend?

Comment: @Raghunandan ...... my activity extends  ....... FragemntActivity

Comment: @CasperSky what is your min sdk in manifest is it below 11 coz actionbar is available natively from 11

Comment: @Raghunandan .... minimum sdk i am using is 14 but my minimum target in future would be 8  .... so 8 is my min target

Comment: @CasperSky extend `ActionBarActivity`. Reference `AppCompat` then do as suggested below in my post. Note : `ActionBatActivity extends FragmentActivity`. use themes dereived from `Theme.AppCompat`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: @CasperSky if its above 11 then there is no need to use AppCompat as actionbar is available natively. Extend Activity and use `android:showAsAction=".."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Support library you need to have your own namespace prefix

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
```

Then change this

```
  android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

to

```
  yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Note : If there is not enough space to display items in the actionbar it will appear in the overflow menu. If you have room for few items it appears on the actionbar and the rest in overflow.

Edit:

```
yourapp:showAsAction="never"
```

From the docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

```
 never  Never place this item in the Action Bar.
```

Comment: @ Raghumandan ..... yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" .... what is your app means ........... i tried to add like this  com.myapp.activities.ActMain:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"  ...please see the edit

Comment: @CasperSky that's a custom namespace. copy paste what is there in my post it self. this `com.findmybuffet.activities.ActMain:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` should be  `yourapp:showAsAction="never"`

Comment: but i get the error as -------  No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' ----- when i try the solution

Comment: @CasperSky have you read my post. If using Support library you must have your own namepsce prefix  `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. read the post again

Comment: I followed the instructions  ....<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:com.myapp.activities.ActMain="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  >   .....still this error pops up ...any ideas why this happenin

Comment: @CasperSky this `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` is not the same as yours is it?. if the namespace is yourapp then `yourapp:showAsAction="never"`

Comment: This is really a frustrating error .... everything looks correct ...... error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.myapp'  .... is what i am recieveig ....i must be doing wrong somewhere else let me analyse this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56262/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-caspersky).

Comment: @CasperSky join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56262/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-caspersky

Comment: yup still not resolved .... does this issue has to do something with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739498/android-action-bar-not-showing-overflow link ....please advice

Answer (score 0):

- Well This was just a workaround to get the answer as below
- Since i am not having the device to test for the solution to test
  Raghunandan answer
- I still believe Raghunandan answer holds good & also sharing what i
  came to do

**Reason for me to test on mobile because:**: "device has a menu-button, the overflow-icon won't show."

---

**Code**::

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
    ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.descriptionID:
        onItemChangeBackground(1);

        Fragment fragContents = FrgBufDetails.newInstance(buf_off_id);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragContents);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        return true;
    case R.id.MapID:
        onItemChangeBackground(2);

        Fragment fragMap = FrgBufLocation.newInstance(buf_off_id);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragMap);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        return true;
    case R.id.galleryID:
        onItemChangeBackground(3);

        Fragment fragGallery = FrgBufGallery.newInstance(buf_off_id);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragGallery);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        return true;
    case R.id.inviteID:
        onItemChangeBackground(4);

        View title = (View) getActivity()
                    .findViewById(R.id.inviteID);

        //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), title);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_sort_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();//showing popup menu

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```